# React Draft Wysiwyg always getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createWithContent') error

Tags: reactjs

My problem is not able render the html code in the editor.
Here is my code for your reference :

```
const divRef = useRef(null);

const [contentState, setContentState] = useState(); // ContentState JSON


const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(divRef.current.innerHTML);
const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
    blocksFromHTML.entityMap
);

this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state)
}
```

I want to render the table data on the editor. Here is my html code for your reference.

```
<div className='row' ref={divRef}>
                    <div className='col-lg-12'>
                        <table id="checklist">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Task List</th>
                                <th>Assignee</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Comments</th>
                            </tr>

                            {

                                ViewChecklistItem.map((row, index) => (

                                    <tr key={row.TaskId}>
                                        <td width="45%">{row.TaskName}</td>
                                        <td>{row.AssigneeName}</td>
                                        <td>

                                            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
                                                <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Status</InputLabel>
                                                <Select
                                                    className={"copy "+(row.AllowStatusChange === 'Y' ? 'allowed' : 'not-allowed')}
                                                    labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
                                                    id="demo-controlled-open-select"
                                                    open={open[index]}
                                                    onClose={() => { handleClose(index) }}
                                                    onOpen={() => { handleOpen(index) }}
                                                    value={status[index] || row.StatusId}
                                                    label="Status"
                                                    onChange={(event, newValue) => { 
                                                        setStatusId(event.target.value);
                                                        setTaskId(row.TaskId);
                                                        setStatusPopup(true);
                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    {StatusList?.map(status => {
                                                        return (

                                                            <MenuItem value={status.StatusId}>{status.Status}</MenuItem>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                                </Select>
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><a href="javascript:;" onClick={() => viewLogs(row.TaskId, row.TaskName, row.AssigneeName)} className='view-log'><img src={view_log} />&nbsp;&nbsp;View Log</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                ))

                            }


                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But am getting the output in console.log(divRef.current.innerHTML);

Please help me out. where I missed.

I have upated Editior code below:

```
 <Editor
                            editorState={editorState}
                            defaultContentState={contentState}
                            onContentStateChange={setContentState}
                            wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                            editorClassName="editor-class"
                            toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                            
                        />
```

Comment: Where is `EditorState` supposed to be defined? Also, I don't think setting `this.state` is going to achieve what you want, if you're using a functional component you'd be much better off adding another `useState`.

Comment: But already tried using EditorState but getting same error 
Am using below code 
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    EditorState.createWithContent(state)
);

Comment: Where does `EditorState` come from though? (The one you are trying to access `createWithContent` on) It's currently undefined.

Comment: When I use EditorState getting same error.

Comment: <Editor
                                editorState={editorState}
                                defaultContentState={contentState}
                                onContentStateChange={setContentState}
                                wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                                editorClassName="editor-class"
                                toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                                
                            />

Comment: I have updated the Editorstate code.